# What android layout should I use for this listview item layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I'm trying to define layout for listview item that looks like attached image (made in Photoshop). What layout(s) should I use?
[image]

Comment: Please, mark the one who helped you as solved.

Comment: I'm working on it, but none of the answers solved my problem completely. I find it hard adjusting padding and margin with your suggestion. I went using GridLayout in stead and I'm almost finished. I will post the code afterwards.

Comment: GridLayout seems a little bit complicated for this, but good luck ;)

Comment: Wel, adjusting padding is harder. At least for me.

Comment: Tell me which are the problematic paddings with my solution and I will try to help.

Comment: Well, all paddings that needs to be done so the layout looks just as the attached image.

Answer (score 1):

i propose a `LinearLayout`with horizontal `orientation` first, and inside a `RelativeLayout`to place other views from left / top  to right / bottom using attributes : `layout_alignParentTop`, `layout_alignParentBottom`, `layout_alignParentLeft`, `layout_alignParentRight` etc ...

Comment: I could buy this if you are talking about putting everything with the white background in the `RelativeLayout`. I still think the `LinearLayout` might not be necessary but that's just my opinion and hard to say without doing some of it. Good answer.

Comment: the `LinearLayout` will contain two block: the white background and the remaining views. the `horizontal` orientation helps keeping it horizontal and aligned. The white background can be a simple `TextView`. The remaining views will be in the `RelativeLayout` and there you use the mentioned attributes.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a `RelativeLayout` for this. Otherwise, you may up with too much nesting. I'm not going to write the layout but you should look through the [RelativeLayout Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) and see all the possible properties you can give `Views`. You may possibly end up with child `LinearLayout`s also and that's ok. But I would use `RelativeLayout` for the parent.

If you are undecided a good thing to do is to draw it out really quick in xml how you think each might go and see with `ViewGroup` seems like the most efficient. Sometimes its hard to say until you get going on it by either writing the xml code or at least some pseudocode.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to play now with paddings and margins.

[image: Result]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/gray_layout"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#888888"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="AUG"/>

        <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="18"/>

        <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2011"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View 
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#000088"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/gray_layout"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/divider"
        android:text="Title"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/divider"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/divider"
        android:text="18. aug 23:49"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/divider"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/divider"
        android:text="Short msg"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/divider"/>

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/info_button"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
        android:background="#ff0000"/>

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/arrow_button"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/info_button"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/info_button"
        android:background="#00ff00"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:layout_above="@id/arrow_button"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/info_button"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/arrow_button"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="30" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can nest multiple LinearLayouts with different orientation to achieve this.